# How to get the indices of sorted list in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, list, sorting

I have a list as shown below:

```
Dim mList As New List(Of Double)
mList.AddRange({3, 2, 5, 3, 6})
```

Now i want to sort it and get the indices of sorted list. For sorting, i can use

```
mList.sort()
```

but how to get the indices of sorted list i.e. (1,0,3,2,4)

Comment: You probably want to use a different collection, as a `Dictionary(Of Integer, Double)` or a `List(Of Class)` (two properties, one for the indexer and one for the associated value), so when you order the collection, the indexer and the associated value are preserved. Or generate a new List of an anonymous type that stores these references

Comment: But i can have repetitive values as well. So this will not work

Comment: How does it matter whether you have duplicate values? Any collection is ordered as your `List(Of Double)` is, except this one cannot preserve the position occupied by a value before the collection was sorted, if this is what you want to do. Otherwise, explain your scenario a little further

Comment: Dictionary can handle duplicate values, the keys are indices which are unique anyway

Comment: Why do you want to get the indices?  This might be an XY problem, where there is a better way to accomplish your ultimate goal than getting back the original locations.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, you can't. When you sort a `List`, it doesn't keep any record of the previous indexes of the items and why would it? It's up to you to do that. There are various options available to you. One is to create an array containing the original items and another array containing the original indexes, then sort them both based on the items array. The index array will then indicate the original indexes of the items. E.g.

```vb
Dim itemsList As New List(Of Integer) From {3, 2, 5, 3, 6}

Dim itemsArray = itemsList.ToArray()
Dim indexesArray = Enumerable.Range(0, itemsArray.Length).ToArray()

Array.Sort(itemsArray, indexesArray)

itemsList.Clear()
itemsList.AddRange(itemsArray)

For i = 0 To itemsList.Count - 1
    Console.WriteLine($"Current index: {i}; Value: {itemsList(i)}; Original index: {indexesArray(i)}")
Next
```